# Is there an open source directions webclient for pgRouting like the directions API from Google?

Tags: web-mapping, pgrouting, routing, direction, osm2pgrouting

I am looking for an open source webclient with (Google) directions functionality (like draggable lines to create extra waypoints) based on an pgrouting database (with an osm2pgrouting topology).

I noticed that there are some examples and demos on the pgrouting site (some are not working anymore), but they are all specific things people have done with pgrouting. They seem to have all created their own specific front end. I am looking for a more generic directions/routing client based on a pgrouting topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this answer is useless 2 years later, but you may want to try [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/). Not based in pgRouting, but is an Open Source routing engine with a Leaflet based API

Comment: I have tried it and it is really good. Not only is it faster for big graphs but it can also give turn directions. It is not useless.

Comment: Happy to hear that. I hope you can use it.